# How to get column names with Saxon EE SQL Extension

Tags: xslt, saxon, exslt

Saxon EE XSLT processor has great [SQL Extension](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/intro.xml). It allows to get results from SQL database right into XSLT. However, I am not able to get table column names into XML. Instead it just uses XML like

```
<row><col>1</col><col>f</col><col>something</col></row>
```

Is there a way to remedy this? I am a little constrained on what technology I can use but it there is another XSLT processor that allows it please let me know.

Comment: Good suggestion, I have implemented it for the next Saxon release.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the Saxon SQL extension because it didn't do quite what I wanted either.
Instead I wrote my own extension in Java. This turned out to be much easier than I expected.

Here's a link that explains how to do this. http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html